# How to curry a function in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

I'm trying to call a 2 parameters function in List.foreach, with the first parameter *fixed* for a loop. In fact I want to curry a function of two parameters into a function of one parameter which returns a function of one parameter (as List.foldLeft do)

This does not work:

```
private def mathFunc1(a: Double, b: Double) =
    println(a + b)


def eval(v: Double) = {
    List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).foreach(mathFunc1(2.1))
}
```

This works:

```
private def mathFunc2(a: Double)(b: Double) =
    println(a + b)


def eval(v: Double) = {
    List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).foreach(mathFunc2(2.1))
}
```

But I don't want to change the signature of mathFunc1, so I want to do something like:

```
private def mathFunc1(a: Double, b: Double) =
    println(a + b)


def eval(v: Double) = {
    List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).foreach(CONVERT_TWO_PARAMS_TO_ONE_ONE(mathFunc1)(2.1))
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
private def mathFunc1(a: Double, b: Double) =
    println(a + b)


def eval(v: Double) = {
    List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).foreach(mathFunc1(2.1, _))
}
```

Underline, the Scala wildcard!

As a minor curiosity, this will also work:

```
def eval(v: Double) = {
    List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).foreach(Function.curried(mathFunc1 _)(2.1))
}
```

Or even:

```
val curriedMathFunc1 = Function.curried(mathFunc1 _)
def eval(v: Double) = {
    List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).foreach(curriedMathFunc1(2.1))
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, just from curiosity, what's the purpose of the parameter v: Double in eval? Every time the results are 3.1, 4.1, 5.1

Comment: @jimakos17 It's not used. That's the way it was on the question, though, so I kept it that way.